# Changing address of inherited members

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, memory-address

I am having a weird problem , and im wondering if **C++11** has a special rule about this I am not aware of.

I have 2 classes :


 1 - **ClNeuron** (abstract) 

 2 - **ClLSTMNeuron** (child of **ClNeuron**)

that are declared as follow:

```
class ClNeuron
{
    protected:

    //Initialization function
    virtual void Init(unsigned long p_uid);

    double Sigmoid(double p_value);
    double SigmoidDerivative(double p_value);

    double TanH(double p_value);
    double TanHDerivative(double p_value);

    public:

    const double CONST_DEFAULT_MOMENTUM_VALUE = 0.1;
    const double CONST_DEFAULT_LEARNING_RATE = 0.05;

    //All of the output connection of this neuron 
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> m_output_connections;

    //Al of the input connection of this neuron
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> m_input_connections;

    bool m_initialized;
    double m_result_buffer;

    //Error related informations
    double m_last_error_delta;  
    double m_error_gradient;

    unsigned long m_uid;
    double m_learning_rate;     

    public:

    bool m_is_bias;
    ClDataSet* m_dataset;

    virtual ~ClNeuron();
    ClNeuron(unsigned long p_uid);
    ClNeuron();


    //Connect this neuron's output to another / others neurons' input
    virtual bool AddOutputConnection(ClNeuron* p_neuron);

    //This neuron got a request to have multiple new input
    virtual std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> InputConnectionRequest(ClNeuron* p_neuron);

    //Tell the neuron to fire the sum of the processed inputs
    virtual double Fire();
    virtual double Fire(double p_data);

    //void ComputeErrorGradient(double p_wanted_output);

    //Function updating all of the current neuron's weight of the OUTPUT connections , depending on an error ratio
    //void UpdateWeights();

    //Set the result buffer using the transfer function . NOTE : This is a pure virtual function
    virtual void ProcessInputs() = 0; 
    virtual bool ComputeErrorGradient() = 0;
    virtual void ComputeWeightDeltas();
    virtual void UpdateWeights();
    virtual void ResetContext();

    //Print neuron & connections & weights
    virtual void PrintNeuronData();
};



class ClLSTMNeuron : public ClNeuron
{
    protected:
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> m_forget_gate_input_connections;
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> m_input_gate_input_connections;
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> m_output_gate_input_connections;
    double m_input_gate_result_buffer;
    double m_output_gate_result_buffer;
    double m_forget_gate_result_buffer;
    double m_cell_state;

    public:
    //Override the ProcessInputs function
    std::vector<ClNeuronConnection*> InputConnectionRequest(ClNeuron* p_neuron);
    void ProcessInputs();
    bool ComputeErrorGradient();
    ClLSTMNeuron();
    virtual ~ClLSTMNeuron();
};
```

The problem is the following :
The **ClLSTMNeuron** constructor call it's parent class function *Init()* , as follow:

```
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron()
{
    ClNeuron::Init(0);
    std::cout << "ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [" << this << "]: my OC [" << &this->m_output_connections << "] has a size of " << this->m_output_connections.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Which, when done, gives me the following output :

```
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC5720B8]: my OC [0000024BBC5720D0] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC5721D0]: my OC [0000024BBC5721E8] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC5722E8]: my OC [0000024BBC572300] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC572400]: my OC [0000024BBC572418] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC572518]: my OC [0000024BBC572530] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC572630]: my OC [0000024BBC572648] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC572748]: my OC [0000024BBC572760] has a size of 0
ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron() [0000024BBC572860]: my OC [0000024BBC572878] has a size of 0
```

In this output, we can clearly see the address of the member *m_output_connections* , of every **ClLSTMNeuron** instances.

But, for an unknown reason, when I instanciate them using a dynamic allocation like this :

```
this->m_neurons = new ClLSTMNeuron[p_number_of_neurons]();
if (this->m_neurons == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "[Fatal Error] ClLSTMNeuronLayer::Init : Impossible to allocate " << p_number_of_neurons << " neurons in memory" << std::endl;
    return false;
}


for (size_t i = 0; i < p_number_of_neurons; i++)
{
    std::cout << "LSTM Neuron " << i << " is at [" << &this->m_neurons[i] << "] and it's OC [" << &this->m_neurons[i].m_output_connections << "] has size of " << this->m_neurons[i].m_output_connections.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following output :

```
LSTM Neuron 0 is at [0000024BBC5720B8] and it's OC [0000024BBC5720D0] h size of 0
LSTM Neuron 1 is at [0000024BBC572150] and it's OC [0000024BBC572168] h size of 18446743758171348710
LSTM Neuron 2 is at [0000024BBC5721E8] and it's OC [0000024BBC572200] h size of 18446743758171348500
LSTM Neuron 3 is at [0000024BBC572280] and it's OC [0000024BBC572298] h size of 315538203026
LSTM Neuron 4 is at [0000024BBC572318] and it's OC [0000024BBC572330] h size of 17994617993471572384
LSTM Neuron 5 is at [0000024BBC5723B0] and it's OC [0000024BBC5723C8] h size of 0
LSTM Neuron 6 is at [0000024BBC572448] and it's OC [0000024BBC572460] h size of 17994617993471572409
LSTM Neuron 7 is at [0000024BBC5724E0] and it's OC [0000024BBC5724F8] h size of 0
```

We can cleary see that addresses of the neuron itself & the address of the member *m_output_connections* have changed : Why would that happen ?
Is there any concept in inheritance / polymorphism and would be not aware of ?

I am thinking about typical pointers problems : Index mismatch, non initialized pointers, etc...
But can't seems to find anything that would trigger this kind of behavior.

Problem is dupplicable in Visual Studio 2015 and GCC Linux.

P.S
You might see something wrong in this code because it doesnt follow non-written rule, like :
Always use a virtual destructor, or similar concept.
Please, feel free let me know any error I might have done.

Thanks again for your time !

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly - you are asking *why* the address of an object changes depending on how it's allocated?

Comment: @UnholySheep: they seem to be reporting erroneous sizes too however.

Comment: @JasonLang yes, that's what's confusing me - because there is no "problem" when it comes to the addresses changing, the only thing that is wrong are the sizes for the vectors

Comment: Well, it seems weird that the addresses of the neuron instances are changing by themselves without an external request...and that seems to apply for the vector members as well, since size() return unexpected values. Am i wrong thinking that both address should be exactly the same, since *ClLSTMNeuron::ClLSTMNeuron()* is called when *new ClLSTMNeuron[p_number_of_neurons]();* is executed ?

Comment: Are you aware that `vector` makes copies of the objects?

Comment: @Charles-UgoBrouillard yes you are wrong - the constructor does not decide an objects address (in fact only the OS decides where you get the allocated memory for anything in your code). And `new` generally allocates in a different "place" than object with automatic storage duration. And if you check your output then the offset between the object's address and the vector stays the same

Comment: Mmm...either I am really tired (which , i hope will be the case) or i am not expressing myself correctly... The constructor & the allocation functions I shared are **not** executed in 2 different contexts... in fact, the allocation is the one calling the constructor.. so , to be clear, in the same thread, the same function :  We call *new ClLSTMNeuron[p_number_of_neurons]* , and the instance have addresses X, and right after, we call the *for (size_t i = 0; i < p_number_of_neurons; i++)* loop, and now, for unknown reasons, they are different addresses ?

Comment: Allocation failure throws an exception; it's redundant to have `if (this->m_neurons == NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
ClNeuron* m_neurons
```

then following would be problematic once you iterate on it:

```
this->m_neurons = new ClLSTMNeuron[p_number_of_neurons]();
```

as pointer arithmetic will consider `ClNeuron` and not `ClLSTMNeuron` for offset computation.

so `m_neurons[n]` is

```
*static_cast<ClNeuron*>(static_cast<char*>(m_neurons) + n * sizeof(ClNeuron))
```

and not expected

```
*static_cast<ClLSTMNeuron*>(static_cast<char*>(m_neurons) + n * sizeof(ClLSTMNeuron))
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand whats going on and what youre asking, the reason the addresses change is because:

```
(14.3) — new T[5] results in a call of operator new[](sizeof(T)*5+x)
```

where x is array initialization overhead

So `new ClLSTMNeuron[p_number_of_neurons]();` isnt making p_number_of_neurons in a contiguous area in memory, it is just reserving enough memory to hold p_number_of_neurons of ClLSTMNeuron.

I am no c++ standard expert, but as far as I understand, the process is something like new[] news up some memory. Then it calls the constructor for ClLSTMNeuron which allocates and initializes ClLSTMNeuron worth of memory and returns a const reference to that memory location. That memory is then moved into the memory aloc'd by new.

or more simply, the constructor sets up some memory which is then moved into the array. So the memory address of this may or may not change.

Again Im not an expert and someone else can probably explain it more properly. If you want to do some research, try reading up on section § 5.3.4 of the c++ [standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Comment: `new T[n]` both allocates memory and constructs `n` contiguous `T`'s in that memory

Comment: @M.M are you sure? the standard clearly states that `The address of the created object will not necessarily be the same as that of the
block if the object is an array` although I am probably reading that wrong

Comment: There could be padding at the start of the allocation, before the start of the first object. The pointer returned by `new T[n]` is the address of the first object (and all `n` objects have been constructed by that time), this may differ from what was returned by the implied call to `operator new[]` but that fact is transparent to the user of `new T[n]`